# Localization — how to check that Filename1 and Filename2 are the same

Tags: .net, windows, internationalization

I want to know that Filename1, provided by the user is the same as stored in DB (Filename2).

I was about to use

```
string.Equals(Filename1, Filename2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

but then I doubted whether I should use `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Obviously, I need to do this the same way OS does, or use appropriate API.

In some cultures, AFAIK, characters (e.g. vocals) may change if the next one is Capitalized.

As I primarily target English-speaking market, I'd like my software to work well throughout the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [Michael Kaplan](http://www.siao2.com/2005/06/12/428429.aspx):

> If you are trying to compare symbolic identifiers or operating system objects like filenames or named pipes, use an Ordinal type method (or an OrdinalIgnoreCase type method).

In other words, use [`StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) as the argument to [`string.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) to mimic the Windows file system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use the invariant culture. I would probably do it without case sensitivity as I'm sure that won't effect the invariant culture (otherwise it wouldn't be a lot of good).

If you consider (I don't know if this is true), that your database was made on a different machine using a different culture, not using the invariant comparison would cause you problems.

If you don't ignore the case, well then if I rename my 'Windows' folder to 'windows' you would say my files within their don't exist anymore, when obviously they do.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are actually existing on disc (which I assume) you can canonicalize the file name using `Directory.GetFiles()` and then compare the canonical file name:

```
string fileName1 = @"C:\someFolder/sOmeFiLE.txt";
string fileName2 = @"C:\somefolder\someFile.txt";

string canonicalFileName1 = Directory.GetFiles(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName1), 
        Path.GetFileName(fileName1))[0];

string canonicalFileName2 = Directory.GetFiles(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName2), 
        Path.GetFileName(fileName2))[0];

bool isEqual = string.Compare(canonicalFileName1, canonicalFileName2) == 0;
```